# Duda formulario PHP para terminos y condiciones

Tags: php, html

```
#MI CODIGO HTML

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Biblioteca</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <header>
            <h1 align="center">Socio</h1>
        </header>
    
        <form action="tablasocio.php" method="post"><br>

            <center>
    
            DNI:<br>
            <input type="text" name="DNI" value="" placeholder="DNI"><br>
            NOMBRE:<br>
            <input type="text" name="NOMBRE" value="" placeholder="NOMBRE"><br>
            CADUCIDAD:<br>
            <input type="date" name="CADUCIDAD" value="" ><br><br>
    
                <td align="center "> <input type="reset" name="Borrar"  id="Borrar" value="Borrar" /></td>
                <td align="center"> <input type="submit" name="enviar"  id="enviar" value="Enviar" /></td>

            </center>
    
        </form>

                <div style="text-align:center;padding:1em 0;"> <h4><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/es/city/3117735"><span style="color:gray;">Hora actual en</span><br />Madrid, España</a></h4> <iframe src="https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/clock-widget-iframe-v2?language=es&size=small&timezone=Europe%2FMadrid" width="100%" height="90" frameborder="0" seamless></iframe> </div>

        <form action="tablasocio.php" method="post">
             <label for="condiciones">Acepta las <a href="socio.html">condiciones</a> y blah blah</label><input type="checkbox" name="condiciones" />
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
#MI CODIGO PHP

<?php  
    
    $dni= $_POST["DNI"];
    $nombre=$_POST["NOMBRE"];
    $caducidad=$_POST["CADUCIDAD"];
    
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_usuario="root";
    $db_contra=NULL ;
    $db_nombre="biblioteca";
    
    
    
    $connexion = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);
    
    if( mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
    
          echo "Hubo un problema con la base de datos error al conectar";
    
          exit() ;
      }
    
   mysqli_select_db($connexion,$db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la Base de datos");
    
   mysqli_set_charset($connexion,"utf8");
    
    
  $instruccion_SQL = "INSERT INTO Socio VALUES('$dni','','$nombre','$caducidad')";
    
   $resultado = mysqli_query($connexion,$instruccion_SQL);
    
   if($resultado == FALSE){
     echo "error en la consulta";
   } else {
     echo "Registro guardado<br><br>";
     echo "<table><tr><td>dni:$dni</td></tr>";
     echo "<tr><td>nombre:$nombre</td></tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>caducidad:$caducidad</td> </tr></table>" ;    
    }        
    mysqli_close($connexion);    

      if( isset( $_POST['condiciones'] ) ) {
       echo  "El cliente aceptó las condiciones";
  } else {
       echo  "El cliente no aceptó las condiciones";
  }
?>
```

Buenas tardes, estoy haciendo un trabajo de una biblioteca y para darle un poco más de curro, he añadido una opcion para terminos y condiciones para hacer que parezca de verdad, el problema me da en la parte del PHP; el error es el siguiente:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'cliente' (T_STRING), expecting ';' or ',' in C:\xampp\htdocs\tablasocio.php on line 44

En principio, al verlo lo revisé y vi que estaban comentadas las lineas, las descomente y puse un echo y nada, sigue saliendo el error; ¿que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: Vale, faltaban abajo unos ";" y las comillas, pero ahora solo me sale que el cliente no ha aceptado las condiciones, no se ahora de donde viene el error

Comment: Lo que veo es que en la linea 44 y linea 46 en donde estan el echo les falta a cada mensaje las comillas y finalizar cada una con punto y coma.   echo  "El cliente aceptó las condiciones";       echo "El cliente no aceptó las condiciones";

Comment: @CarlosCespedes me he dado cuenta de eso, pero ahora solo me sale que "el cliente no ha aceptado" no me sale ningún boton de aceptar o rechazar y ya no se donde está el fallo

Comment: EStoy viendo que los tags de form envian ta peticion al mismo script de php (tablasocio.php). Pensaria que lo mas optimo es dejar el label y el input de condiciones dentro del primer form. Puede que le este entrando en conflicto, debido a que al diligenciar el primer form, al enviar los parametros de $_post, no este el valor de condiciones

Comment: Deberías escapar los datos que recibes desde el cliente, por seguridad y por buenas practicas. Usa sentencias preparadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el momento existen dos form cada uno con un boton que envian los valores de los campos al mismo script. En el primero estan los inputs DNI, NOMBRE y CADUCIDAD. en el segundo solo esta condiciones. Lo que veo es que al realizar click en el boton de enviar del primer form solo va enviar 3 parametros y en el script de php al que llegan tablasocio.php llegan los 3 pero hay una condicional que dice

```
if( isset( $_POST['condiciones'] ) ) {
  echo  "El cliente aceptó las condiciones";
} else {
  echo "El cliente no aceptó las condiciones";
}
```

En la cual el parametro condiciones no existe. Cual seria la solucion. Dejar un solo form con los 4 inputs, con eso llegan los 4 parametros

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Biblioteca</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <header>
            <h1 align="center">Socio</h1>
        </header>
    
        <form action="tablasocio.php" method="post"><br>

            <center>
    
            DNI:<br>
            <input type="text" name="DNI" value="" placeholder="DNI"><br>
            NOMBRE:<br>
            <input type="text" name="NOMBRE" value="" placeholder="NOMBRE"><br>
            CADUCIDAD:<br>
            <input type="date" name="CADUCIDAD" value="" ><br><br>

            <div>
            <label for="condiciones">Acepta las <a href="socio.html">condiciones</a> y blah blah</label><input type="checkbox" name="condiciones" />
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
            </div>
    
                <td align="center "> <input type="reset" name="Borrar"  id="Borrar" value="Borrar" /></td>
                <td align="center"> <input type="submit" name="enviar"  id="enviar" value="Enviar" /></td>

            </center>
    
        </form>


    </body>
    </html>
```